# how to read a huge array of bytes in chunks - pj_strset

Tags: ios, objective-c, char, pjsip

I am working on an iOS project

I have to read a huge file in chunks of 4KB
Here is what I have so far:

```
NSData *fileData= [self getBytesFromInput];
pj_str_t text;
int chunkSize = 4*1024;
int fileSize = [fileData length];

while (fileSize>0){

if (fileSize<=chunkSize) {
chunkSize = fileSize;
fileSize=0;
}
else fileSize = fileSize-chunkSize;

pj_strset(&text, (char*)[fileData bytes], MIN([fileData length], chunkSize); //takes the first chunk
    //BUT HOW TO TAKE THE NEXT CHUNK OF DATA?

//do something with the &text ....
}
```

Comment: are'nt you loading the whole file at once with `NSData *fileData= [self getBytesFromInput];` ?

Comment: yes I am loading the entire file in NSData *fileData. I want to put in &text , chunks of 4KB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would refactor the code so you are also loading the files in chunks, but you can access the later chunks by adding an offset to your byte-pointer:

```
int currentOffset = 0;

while (fileSize>0) {
  ...
  char* bytePointer = (char*)[fileData bytes];
  pj_strset(&text, bytePointer+currentOffset, MIN([fileData length], chunkSize);
  currentOffset += chunkSize;
}
```

**EDIT:**

This should do the same thing but reading the file chunk for chunk:

```
NSString *yourFilePath;
NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:yourFilePath];
int chunksize = 4*1024;
pj_str_t text;
NSData *data;

while ((data = [fileHandle readDataOfLength:chunksize]) && [data length] > 0) {
  pj_strset(&text, (char*)[data bytes], [data length]);
}
```

Comment: what is the filePointer? Could u define it please?

Comment: sorry, should have been bytePointer.

Comment: great answer. Thank you. When receiving the files on the client side (let s say the server is sending these chunks to the client on udp socket). what is important ti check on the client side?